# how to identify message pop-up with SAP GUI script?

Tags: python, vba, sap-gui

I want to identify this pop-up, how do I do it?

[image]

I'm trying like this, but it won't work:

```
 sap_gui_auto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
 application = sap_gui_auto.GetScriptingEngine
 connection = application.Children(0)
 session = connection.Children(0)
 time.sleep(2)
 if  session.Info.ScreenNumber == "0200":
    print('achei ')
 else:
    print('nao achei ')
```

Comment: That code doesn't look like it's searching for that window.  Did you try the simple option of looking for a top window with the title "Exibir logs"?

Comment: How do I identify the window?

Comment: Did you search the tools specialized in identifying the SAP GUI element IDs? (`screenreader.exe` at SAP Support web site, and Scripting Tracker for SAP GUI Scripting by Stefan Schnell)

Answer (score 0):

If it is really a pop up window it will have the name `wnd[1]`in most cases. One could check for that like

```
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
   ' Code in case the active window has the name wnd[1]
Else
    ' Code for the other case 
End If
```

Comment: Hi good morning, this is correct, but would there be a way to copy the information and add it to a variable?

Comment: Yes, that's possible but I'm afraid without further information it's difficult to provide help. As mentioned in one of the comments it's a good idea to use Stefan Schnell's Scripting Tracker. That is a most helpful tool. Apart from that you asked for guidance on identifying the window.